# When using a trackBar to move through images in pictureBox when getting to the last image in the array getting exception out of range. How to solve?

Tags: c#, winforms

The exception is on the line

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(images[(int)value]);
```

It happens when I'm moving the trackBar to the right to the end and at the last one the exception is thrown.

The problem is that there is 35 images in the array and also the value is 35.

How can i solve it?

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

There is 35 images in the array and the value is 35 when the exception happens.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyImages
{
    public partial class Editor : Form
    {
        private string[] images;

        public Editor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //images = 

            images = GetImages();
            macTrackBar2.Maximum = images.Length;
        }

        private void Editor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        public string[] GetImages()
        {
            string rootPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"d:\MyImages");
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath).GetDirectories()
                .OrderByDescending(d => d.CreationTimeUtc)
                .First();
            FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.gif");

            images = files.Select(f => f.FullName).ToArray();

            Array.Sort(images, new MyComparer(true));

            return images;
        }

        private class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
        {
            public static readonly MyComparer Descending = new MyComparer(false);

            [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);

            public int Compare(string psz1, string psz2)
            {
                return (Reverse ? -1 : 1) * StrCmpLogicalW(psz1, psz2);
            }

            public MyComparer(bool reverse)
            {
                Reverse = reverse;
            }

            public bool Reverse { get; private set; }
        }

        private void macTrackBar2_ValueChanged(object sender, decimal value)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(images[(int)value]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The values are in the range `(0; images.Length - 1)` -- Not sure what kind of TrackBar you're using.

Comment: Off-topic, but make sure you dispose the images later when you don't need them. Also if there's a possibility of having many images in the directory, then it's not a good idea to preload them all into the array.

Comment: macTrackBar2.Maximum = images.Length - 1;